# Set WordPress post format via post-new

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to set a post to the Post Type "Status" at the time I create a new post. I don't want to have to check the box because that is one more click. I was hoping a kind of syntax for my bookmark like: wp-admin/post-new.php?post_format=Status would do the trick but it doesn't seem to work. I don't want to change my default format, I want to do it at new post creation.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: I guess what you want here is to have a specific post format for a custom post type. You can use the `get_the_terms` hook.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `save_post` action to do that referenced [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)

```
function update_post_status( $post_id ) {
  set_post_type( $post_id, 'status' );

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_post_status' );
```

Edit: You can perform checks accordingly to validate and check if you're working on the post you'd actually like to update. More validation techniques in the codex link examples.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want here is to have a specific post format for a custom post type. Below is the code that might help. I have used the `get_the_terms` hook to get all the terms and for a specific post type return only audio post format. You can change audio with whatever post format you wish to have.

Please replace `your_post_type_name` with what post type you are using.

```
add_filter( 'get_the_terms', 'my_post_format_terms', 10, 3 );

function my_post_format_terms( $terms, $post_id, $tax ) {

    if ( 'post_format' === $tax && empty( $terms ) && 'your_post_type_name' === get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {

        $audio = get_term_by( 'slug', 'post-format-audio', $tax );

        $terms = array( $audio );
    }

    return $terms;
}
```